# How can i scroll to an anchor?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, scroll, datapager

I have bound a datapager control to a listview.

I would like to scroll to the first item of the listview control on the DataPager click.  I think this should be done with javascript. It seems that the datapager does not allow that.

What options do I have?  How can I scroll to a specific anchor when clicking on the DataPager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascript function *scrollIntoView* for that on client side or on "server side":
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ViewControl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use the basic html [named anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations) to scroll to a specific anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim!

And for the lazy guys out there (just like me ;), here is the VB.NET equivalent. 
It contains typo corrections and the new [RegisterClientScriptBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        FocusControlOnPageLoad("Label1", Me.Page)
 End Sub

 Public Sub FocusControlOnPageLoad(ByVal ClientID As String, ByVal page As System.Web.UI.Page)
        Dim csName As String = "ScrollViewScript"
        Dim csType As Type = Me.GetType
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = page.ClientScript
        If Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName) Then
            Dim csText As New StringBuilder()
            csText.Append("<script>function ScrollView(){")
            csText.Append("var el = document.getElementById('" & ClientID & "');")
            csText.Append("if (el != null){")
            csText.Append("el.scrollIntoView();")
            csText.Append("el.focus();}}")
            csText.Append("window.onload = ScrollView;")
            csText.Append("</script>")
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub
```